# Since a few days im not able to select or click html tags on my SVG (Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, svg

Since a few days my clickable tags inside my SVG stopped working in google chrome. It's weird and i have tried "everything" and it's STILL not working. This only happens in "Google Chrome" (i'm using Versions 67 and 68 beta)!

Halfway through my SVG I can't click or select anything anymore. it does not have to do with the nav list (the same happens with div tags).

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="4984" height="3534" viewBox="0 0 4984 3534">
    <svg id="side_1" x="0" y="0" width="2000" height="3534"  version="1.1">

        <foreignobject x="118" y="348" width="1406" height="2895">
            <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <nav class="section__list"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>test ?</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#">Can't click this</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li class="section__block" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Can't select this</h2>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </body>
        </foreignobject>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For some reasons MC.Hammer came to my mind ;-) So I can repro on Chrome 67, but not on 69 nor on 70 (Canary).  So it might mean they already did fix it.

Comment: I have just downloaded Chrome version 65, and this version is working properly! But this doesn't solve the problem for my users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Chrome 69 See http://crbug.com/859461.